# How to have more precision at the end of the y-axis using plot() with R

Tags: r, plot

I want something like this image.

[image]

I want to plot a logarithmic graph, and set the y-axis to take (**to display, with same *interval***) the following values.

```
values <- c(seq(0, 0.50, 0.25), seq(0.60, 0.90, 0.10), seq(0.91, 1, 0.01))
```

This is how my code looks like now :

```
...
y_axis <- c(seq(0, 0.50, 0.25), seq(0.60, 0.90, 0.10), seq(0.91, 1, 0.01))
perc <- lapply(y_axis, function(x)quantile(data[,numCol], c(x), na.rm=TRUE, type=1))
graphPer <- tkrplot(fenetreGraph, function(){plot(perc, y_axis, type="l", col="blue", yaxt = "n"); axis(2, list_y_axis, las=2)})
tkgrid(graphPer, row=0, column=3)
...
```

it gives me this

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Convert them to (ordered) factor.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean to do.

Comment: Please give a reproducible example of the code you use now for plotting.